# solving 8 puzzle problem with BFS DFS (Using Python. Needs some suggestion)

Tags: python, graph, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

My final state is

> 0 1 2 
>  3 4 5 
>  6 7 8

my graph would look like this

```
graph = {0 :[1, 3],
         1 :[0, 4, 2],
         2 :[1, 5],
         3 :[0, 4, 6],
         4 :[1, 3, 5, 7],
         5 :[2, 4, 8],
         6 :[3, 7],
         7 :[4, 6, 8],
         8 :[5 ,7]
        }
```

1 - I was wondering if I should try some other methods such as list, if else statement than graph(above).
2 - Is anything wrong with the graph?
The problem given -

> Example [1,5,3,2,0,4,7,8,6] <- more like this 
>  1 5 3 
>  2 0 4
>   
>  7 8 6

I am supposed to find final state with given state

Thank You

Comment: do you create that `graph` dict manually?

Answer (score 0):

So, there are 4 corner cases:

- Top row
- Bottom row
- Most left column
- Most right column

(And combinations)

We can handle them easy like this:

```
data = [1, 5, 3,
        2, 0, 4,
        7, 8, 6]

width = 3
height = 3

graph = {number: list() for number in data}

for idx, number in enumerate(data):
    current_height = int(idx / width)
    current_width = idx % width

    if current_width != width - 1:  # if next element in same row
        graph[number].append(data[idx + 1])

    if current_width != 0:  # if prev element in same row
        graph[number].append(data[idx - 1])

    if current_height != 0:  # if there is top element
        graph[number].append(data[idx - 3])

    if current_height != height - 1:  # if there is bottom element
        graph[number].append(data[idx + 3])

import pprint
pprint.pprint(graph)
```

This code will construct graph, but is this all for that puzzle?.

Answer (score 0):

```
def dfs_recursive(graph, source,path = []):  
  
       if source not in path:  
           path.append(source)  
  
           if source not in graph:  
               # leaf node, backtrack  
               return path  
  
           for neighbour in graph[source]:  
  
               path = dfs_recursive(graph, neighbour, path)  
  
  
       return path  
         
graph = {0 :[1, 3],
         1 :[0, 4, 2],
         2 :[1, 5],
         3 :[0, 4, 6],
         4 :[1, 3, 5, 7],
         5 :[2, 4, 8],
         6 :[3, 7],
         7 :[4, 6, 8],
         8 :[5 ,7]
        }
dfs_element = dfs_recursive(graph, 0)  
print(dfs_element)
```